# C++: Unwanted Number Added to Output

Tags: c++, output, ostream

I'm writing a C++ program that converts a decimal number to binary and hexadecimal.
The problem is that for some reason it concatenates the number "1875954912" to both representations every time.

I've tried a bunch of things - mainly changing up how the program calculates numArrayLength and the for-loop in my decToBase function, but I haven't been able to figure out why this happens yet.

The program is not complete by the way - it doesn't turn integers bigger than 9 into letters for the hex representation yet, but that's not my main concern right now.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int howManyBitsNeeded(int someNum, int base) {
    int numOfDivisions = 0;
    while (someNum != 0) {
        someNum = floor(someNum / base);
        numOfDivisions += 1;
    }
    return numOfDivisions;
}


int decToBase(int someNum, int base) {
    int bitsNeeded = howManyBitsNeeded(someNum,base);
    int numArrayLength = bitsNeeded;
    int numArray[bitsNeeded];

    while (bitsNeeded > 0) {
        numArray[bitsNeeded] = (someNum % base);
        someNum = floor(someNum / base);
        bitsNeeded -= 1;
    }

    for (int k = (numArrayLength-1); k >= 0; --k) {
        cout << numArray[(numArrayLength - k)];
    }

}


int main() {
    int inpNum;

    cout << "Enter your number: ";
    cin >> inpNum;

    cout << "Binary representation: " << decToBase(inpNum,2) << endl;
    cout << "Hexadecimal representation: " << decToBase(inpNum,16);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's what the output looks like:

```
Enter your number: 25
Binary representation: 110011875954912
Hexadecimal representation: 191875954912
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `decToBase` *return*? And *is* it supposed to return something, or only to print something, or do both?

Comment: Array indexes start at `0` (not `1`), and end at `size-1` (not `size`) - where `size` is the amount of items in the array. Keep that in mind when reading the `decToBase` function, and specifically the first time `numArray[bitsNeeded] = (someNum % base);` is executed, as well as the output loop.

Comment: It seems you access not allocated index of array, `numArray`. Check while loop in `decToBase`.

Comment: Firstly, `int numArray[bitsNeeded]` is not standard C++ when `bitsNeeded` is a variable.   Use a standard container , like `std::vector<int>` instead.   Second, you are treating array indexing as if it is one-based (i.e. elements `1` to `bitsNeeded`).   Array indexing in C++ is zero based - valid indices start at `0`.   Accessing past the end as you are gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `decToBase` is declared as returning an `int`, but it doesn't actually return anything. Your compiler should warn you about this. Since you're not returning anything here, change its return type to `void`. Then instead of trying to print its return value, simply call the function without printing it:

```
std::cout << "Binary representation: ";
decToBase(inpNum, 2); // this already prints the number, no need to pass it to std::cout
std::cout << endl;

std::cout << "Hexadecimal representation: ";
decToBase(inpNum, 16);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or of course you can change the function to return the string that you want to print instead of printing it inside the function.

Also, there's an issue here:

```
int numArray[bitsNeeded];
```

This is out of range when you try to access it here:

```
while (bitsNeeded > 0) {
        numArray[bitsNeeded] = (someNum % base);
```

And also later when you try to print it. To get rid of this off by one error, you have to change this to

```
numArray[bitsNeeded-1] = (someNum % base);
```

And in the output change it to

```
cout << numArray[(numArrayLength - k -1)];
```

And while you're at it, instead of having it as a VLA ([which isn't part of C++ and only works if the compiler tolerates it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)), I would recommend a vector:

```
std::vector<int> numArray(bitsNeeded+1); // include <vector> for this to work
```

Furthermore, note that integer division is already truncated, so unless you plan to support negative numbers later on, you can silence a warning about implicit `double` to `int` conversion by changing this:

```
someNum = floor(someNum / base);
```

To this:

```
someNum /= base;
```